# Ckeditor - Cursor position always gets to the start after setData

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor

I'm using angular, and set the data of ckeditor with ngModel - when we render we set the data

editor.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);

We try to keep the cursor selection with ranges and bookmarks

but it always get to the start even if there are no DOM changes

I've tried many solutions such as

[CKEditor: set cursor/caret positon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742599/ckeditor-set-cursor-caret-positon)

[Set cursor to specific position in CKEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835365/set-cursor-to-specific-position-in-ckeditor)

Couldn't make it work... :(

Can anyone help please...

Answer (score 2):

This will work for Ckeditor5:

```
editor.model.change( writer => {writer.setSelection( editor.model.document.getRoot(), 'end' );} );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var range = editor.createRange();
range.moveToElementEditablePosition( editor.editable(), true );
editor.getSelection().selectRanges( [ range ] );
```

Got it from this link
[Set cursor to specific position in CKEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835365/set-cursor-to-specific-position-in-ckeditor)

Comment: Sorry, You have already post this link, if it doesn't work, please ignore it.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I've tried the bookmarks as well and it doesn't seem to work - any ideas?

Comment: I think it's because you changed the text before bookmark, so the bookmark address's element changed.

Comment: Or you can try this method editor.getSelection().selectBookmarks([bookmark])

Comment: Thanks again - the problem with setting bookmarks is that I change the dom, elements are added so the ranges and selection no longer match - so I can't use the bookmarks of before my change